# Heating in Battery area of the laptop ...!

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, overheating, tlp

There was huge battery drain and overheating on my laptop while running XUbuntu I fixed that to an extent with tlp and powertop . Now my cpu runs cool and fan noise is almost gone but the palm rest area heats up this leads to dis comfort while typing . This area holds the battery so whats the solution to minimise this or fix this problem .

Laptop Specifications :
CPU : i7 8550u
GPU : nvidia mx150 2gb
RAM : 16gb
Storage : 1tb HDD + 128gb SSD (Xubuntu installed on the HDD)

(LAPTOP MODEL Asus S15 S510UN)

Thank you in advance ...!

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: yes i was running the opensource drivers by Nouveau now changed to the nvidia proprietary drivers 390

Comment: Then everything is OK. You can switch to Intel GPU to reduce heating.

Comment: I've already done that

Comment: So everything is OK then. It is hardware specific.

Comment: This one thing is making me want to switch over to windows ... just because of the warmer palm rest ... This even happend when I installed manjaro i3 edition .

Comment: I am sure on Windows it will be same. I see no reason why not.

Comment: No I still have windows on this machine and that has no such issues.